# Where can I find a Textmate bundle for BibDesk autocompletion?

Tags: mac, auto-completion, bibdesk, textmate

I would like to be able to insert citations automatically from BibDesk (v. 1.7.5) while using Textmate (v. 2.0.6), not TeXShop. Over a year and a half ago, @AdamMaxwell [mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444988/autocompletion-of-citation-with-bibdesk-but-without-texshop/445254#445254) that he had written a Textmate bundle to make that possible, but I have been unable to track it down.

Is the bundle available somewhere? Or is there some other way to obtain the same functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My TextMate bundle for BibDesk autocompletion is available from my DropBox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fwj50u3lmq6m63g/BibDeskTMCompletions.zip?dl=0

The .zip file is dated October 2019. Here are the instructions I emailed to someone at that time:

I no longer remember how to give a TextMate command to someone, so here's a screenshot of the bundle settings, and the ruby code follows. You'll have to edit the CMD variable in ruby to point to BibDeskTMCompletions, but I just hacked this to work with TextMate 2.0, and it seemed to work fine.

Let me know if this works! I used to have a ReadMe with instructions and the .tmCommand, but that was three computers ago.

[image: Bundle settings]

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -wKU

# for TextMate.exit
require ENV["TM_SUPPORT_PATH"] + "/lib/exit_codes.rb"
require ENV["TM_SUPPORT_PATH"] + "/lib/ui.rb"

SUPPORT = ENV['TM_SUPPORT_PATH']
DIALOG = ENV['DIALOG']

require SUPPORT + '/lib/escape'
require SUPPORT + '/lib/osx/plist'
#require "#{ENV['TM_BUNDLE_SUPPORT']}/lib/LaTeXUtils.rb"
require ENV['TM_BUNDLE_SUPPORT'] + '/lib/Ruby/latex.rb'

latexMaster = LaTeX.master(ENV['TM_LATEX_MASTER'] || ENV['TM_FILEPATH'])
if !latexMaster
  latexMaster = ""
end

searchTerm = STDIN.read

# omit -s to return all items
CMD = '"$HOME"/BuildProducts/Debug/BibDeskTMCompletions ' + (searchTerm == "" ? "" : "-s #{searchTerm}") + ' -t "$TM_FILEPATH" ' + latexMaster

# returns an XML plist
plist = `#{CMD}`

# cribbed from example on pastie
res = OSX::PropertyList::load(`#{e_sh DIALOG} -up #{e_sh plist}`)

# this keeps us from overwriting on cancel
TextMate.exit_discard unless res.has_key? 'selectedMenuItem'

# insert valueForKey:@"citeKey"
print res['selectedMenuItem']['citeKey']
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the terribly elementary question, but how do I install this bundle? When I unzipped the file, it resulted in a file without an extension. Should I rename it? And which directory should I put it in? (If this is too much to ask in a comment, let me know, and I'll start a new question.)

Comment: Alex, hopefully this gets you going with it. I should look up how to export a proper TextMate command, but I'm lazy.

Comment: Thanks for this, Adam! I'll see if I can get it to work.